# Plivo - Is there a way to put delay between loops in a voice call?

Tags: c#, plivo

I'm using Plivo's API to make phone calls and the [Speak](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/detailed-reference/xml/speak/) element to dictate what has to be said during the call.

I'm also using the `loop` parameter to repeat the message twice. However, I would like to to put a delay before the message Is said the second time.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Would putting a `Thread` to sleep, i.e. `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeInMiliseconds);` sufice? This will however block the Thread from where it's called for the specified period. If you're calling this from the main thread, you may use `Timer` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I didn't use the mentioned library hence I gave you a generic answer.